# How to assess the damage to the lawn mower after hitting an iron pipe?

Tags: lawn-mower

I have a Ariens self propelled lawnmower that I happend to hit a iron marker(pipe) with. When the blade hit the pipe, the lawnmower jolted and the engine stopped and I have not been able to start the engine since then.

I took a look and the blade still intact except for a nick on the edge; still has a balanced spin ( meaning it doesn't hit the walls of the mowing case ) when I spin it by hand. It has fresh gas and oil. There are no spills anywhere.

I don't what else to do  or where else to check. Is there anything else i should check before taking it to be repaired? Thanks!

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/32965/craftsman-push-mower-wont-start-after-hitting-stump.   Try this link for an answer. This is off topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the Link. I didn't know about that website.

Comment: Many walk behind lawnmowers have the engine directly coupled to the mower blade.  It's possible a good solid slam could break the crankshaft.

Answer (score 1):

The flywheel key is made to shear when things happen like you described. I had it happen a few times over the years. Pull the top of the motor off, remove the flywheel replace the key, and reassemble.

Answer (score 1):

I hit a two inch pipe stub that was sticking up out of the ground with a push lawn mower. The mower stopped totally dead instantly with a huge thrack of the blade against the pipe.

I coundn't get it restarted because the shock had dislodged the spark plug connection. Once I discovered that and reseated the spark plug cord I did get it to startup and it tried to run. Unfortunately the drive shaft had become bent and the whole mower vibrated so bad that I could barely hold onto the thing.

Needless to say that resulted in a need to buy a new mower.